# Styling dynamically generated HTML

Tags: html, css

I have two containers where I store my dynamically created content

```
<div id="myTabContent1" class="tab-content">
   <div id="s1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
```

Once I generate the content, it looks like this:

```
<div id="myTabContent1" class="tab-content">
  <div id="s1" class="tab-pane fade in">
    <iframe src="something">
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I want to style that `<html>` tag. This is my try but it doesn't work.

```
#myTabContent1 > div > iframe > html{
     padding-left:20px !important;
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was <iframe> that was causing the problems.

Comment: Is your iframe controller by you or third party ?